# Unhandled exception error, android

Tags: android, json

I fetch my json object to the function but I have unhandled exception error, is anyone knows about this problem, appreciated sample code!

Thanks!

//Here is the error, when I want to fetch the object = jsonObj
//acctually the error is in the code I cann't run it, it's a red line from //TestValidator.validateDateWithCriteria(testCriteria, jsonObj);

```
   return TestValidator.TestWithCriteria(testCriteria, jsonObj);
}
```

Comment: Please upload the error log with question.

Comment: post the LogCat of the exception

Comment: @Kedarnath Thanks for the comment error is on the code I cannot run it, I have redline for all after return DateValidator.validateDateWithCriteria(validationCriteria, jsonObj);

Comment: @panini Thanks for the comment error is on the code I cannot run it, I have redline for all after return DateValidator.validateDateWithCriteria(validationCriteria, jsonObj);

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, you should open the Problems View and copy and paste the error message here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your definition of `DateValidator#validateDateWithCriteria()` you have said that it throws an `Exception`.

However, when you call the method, you aren't putting it in a `try/catch` block. Because you have said you will throw an `Exception`, you must attempt to catch this potential `Exception` whenever you call the method. for example:

```
try{
     return DateValidator.validateDateWithCriteria(validationCriteria, jsonObj);
}catch(Exception ex){
    Log.e("Your Tag", "DateValidator", ex);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: should i add null or false as a return since it is boolean?thanks

Comment: you should add whichever makes more sense in your case, probably false